# Displaying newly generated images in React

Tags: reactjs, flask

My Flask `POST` request invoked from React generates and writes a new image file to disk. I would like to display this image every time after a successful call. I am able to display static, pre-existing files with `<img src={require("./img/image.png")}/>`, but `<img src={require("./img/" + result)}/>` doesn't work, where `result` is the name of a newly generated file returned by Flask. `<img src={require("./img/" + result).default}/>` doesn't help either. Is there a known workaround?

Also, could this have anything to do with the deployment mode? Currently, I deploy with Node serve as `serve -s build`. Completely new to React and webdev in general.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with base64 encoding the `result` string in Flask and displaying as `<img src={"data:image/png;base64," + result}/>`, but will be happy to see a less hacky solution.